# Animate table row into another element

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a page which contains a trash can image element, and a table near it.

I cannot figure out a way to properly do a jquery animation such that when i click the link in the table row, the table row would animate into the trash can.

Most solutions I can find seem to only look at animating the table rows within the tables themselves, but I would like to MOVE the row out of the table and animate it into the trash can element I have on my page.

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the position of the row on the window, then make it `position:absolute;` at that location, then animate() it to the trash, and make it smaller. Then fade it out once its positioned above the trash.

Comment: this is the solution I'm using right now and it's working great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/QWgRF/409/

**Here is samle jsfidle to help you you can do same using jquery dragable..**
you can use

```
 $(function() {
 $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
 });
```

Comment: Nice approach, although one bug in the fiddle is that if you drag over the trash but then drag away (but not over the original table) then the item still gets deleted

Answer (score 0):

I would do something a bit like this.

One important proviso is that the shrinking into the trash can will only work properly if all measurements (margin, padding, font-size, width, height etc) within the table are defined in `ems`... and even then it might not work (the below just represents what woudl be my first stab at the problem).

```
var theTableRow = $(get the row);
// creating a duplicate rather than moving the original in order to preserve layout of the table
var newTable = $('<table class='same as on your original table'></table>')
                .html('<tbody class='same as on your original table'></tbody>')
                .children()
                .html(theTableRow.clone())
                .end();

newTable.css({
   // you'll need to adjust these values for padding and margin too
   left: get the left offset of the row,
   top: get the top offset of the row,
   position: 'absolute'
});

newTable.appendTo('body')
theTableRow.css('visibility', 'hidden');

newTable.animate({
   left: left offset of trashcan,
   top: top offset of trashcan,
   width: 0,
   height: 0,
   opacity: 0,
   font-size: 0
}, function () {
    theTableRow.remove(); // or you could slowly animate the height to 0 before removing
});
```